# ScrollTop not reverting back when scroll to top

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

Having problems with Scrolltop - have got it to change smoothly when scrolling down, but doesn't revert to the original css when scrolling back up.

I've tried switching the order around but nothing works. Can anyone tell me where my code is wrong?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    var topblock = $(".topblockfix");
    var header = $(".header");
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.topblockfix').offset().top) {
        if (scroll >= 250) {
            topblock.removeClass("topblockfix").addClass("topblockfix-alt");
            header.removeClass("header").addClass("header-alt");
        } else {
            topblock.removeClass("topblockfix-alt").addClass("topblockfix");
            header.removeClass("header-alt").addClass("header");
        }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical mistake in the first if-statement.

You are checking the offset top of $('.topblockfix'). But you remove the class .topblockfix and set it to .topblockfix-alt.

So you need to update your if statement:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.topblockfix').offset().top || $(window).scrollTop() > $('.topblockfix-alt').offset().top) {
```

or you have to cache the value of $('.topblockfix').offset().top somewhere

Comment: That made sense. However, it didn't work. So I changed it to an id that doesn't change - didn't work - then changed the > to >= and now it does! Thanks for the help getting my brain to work :-)  ``` if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#topblock').offset().top) { ```